# C# dotnet build with source generators

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild

i have source generator in my .net5.0 project. In Visual Studio everything goes well but when i try to build app using dotnet cli source generator does not run:

```
error CS1061: 'CentralSystemResponseSender' does not contain a definition for 'SendResponseAsync' and no accessible extension method 'SendResponseAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'CentralSystemResponseSender' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

MSBuild version: `Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.9.0+57a23d249 for .NET`

---

### Edit

`msbuild -t:Rebuild` in visual studio developer powershell build succeeded but i can`t use that in Gitlab CI/CD

Project structure:

```
-- Project.Api
     /-- SourceGenerator.A
  /-- Project.Domain
     /-- SourceGenerator.B
```

`dotnet build "Project.Domain.csproj"` success
`dotnet build "Project.Api.csproj"` throws error because `SourceGenerator.B` does not generate code.
Build whole solution also works but `dotnet publish` again throws error because `SourceGenerator.B` does not generate code.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "generators/SourceGenerator.A/SourceGenerator.A.csproj"
RUN dotnet restore "generators/SourceGenerator.B/SourceGenerator.B.csproj"
RUN dotnet restore "src/Project.Domain/Anaconda.Domain.csproj"
RUN dotnet restore "src/Project.Api/Project.Api.csproj"
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.Api.dll"]
```

Project.Api.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>..\..</DockerfileContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset" Version="3.9.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\generators\Project.Generator.A\Project.Generator.A.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Domain\Anaconda.Domain.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Project.Domain.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\generators\Project.Generator.B\Project.Generator.B.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Hi and congratulations for your first question on StackOveflow! Are you using a publicly avilable generator or do you have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces this? A verbose build log or [binary log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild?view=vs-2019#save-a-binary-log) (warning: contains paths, environment variables and project file content) could help here.

Comment: You could also try to build from the developer command prompt with `msbuild -t:Rebuild` to see if this is an issue with the generator as the `dotnet` cli runs the generator on .NET 5 but VS and MSBuild run the generator on .NET Framework. (but at this point this is speculation)

Comment: Source generators works fine in visual studio, i think problem is in build commands because dotnet publish ignores generator in dependency

Comment: @MartinUllrich i updated question, any idea?

Comment: I think it can be problem with `RegisterForSyntaxNotifications` because that error i posted says file is generater but containing methods didn`t which works with dotnet build

Comment: Can you try .NET 6? Source generators are not officially supported before .NET 6 SDK

Comment: I had a similar problem in a .NET 6 solution using [Amadevus.RecordGenerator](https://github.com/amis92/RecordGenerator), which uses older Roslyn-based source generators.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Did you solve this issue? Can you share how?Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Daniel I just add package "Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset" to Project.Domain.csproj, solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answers helps other people 2 years after.

We had the same issue but as Vincent said in the comments was resolved by adding the "Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset" to the **.csproj** of the project that has the source generator project referenced as an analyzer.

```
    <ItemGroup>
        ...
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset" Version="4.8.0">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\DocumentationGenerator\DocumentationGenerator.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" TargetFramework="netstandard2.0" />
        ...
    <ItemGroup>
```